# Tomcat 7.0.72 - JRE_HOME is different form JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, tomcat

When I run Tomcat I see that value for JRE_HOME:

```
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
```

While my current JAVA_HOME is different:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

It seems like Tomcat is using two different java version: JDK 1.8 as JRE_HOME and JDK 1.7 as JAVA_HOME.

Can I force Tomcat to use my JAVA_HOME as JRE_HOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify those settings (among others) in the [`setenv.sh`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) script (`setenv.bat` in Windows).